# Is it possible to deploy a Visual Studio project as a Web App without installing Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio Web Project as a Web Application (MVC project) which I need to deploy to an Azure account. I have the entire project as a ZIP file. Is it possible to directly publish the project on Azure without installing Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that should be possible. You have multiple options:
- FTP
- Sync with a cloud folder
- CLI tools
- Deploy from Git

There is an article that describes these: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy

If it is a once off just use FTP. If you are making changes in another editor then setup Git or CLI commands to automate it. I have no experience with the syncing with a cloud older.